# Navigating from one page to another not working

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to make a books app, and I want to change the frame programmatically by calling the function frameChanger from another class. But it is not working, and instead of calling the PageReader page, it calls the ListRetrieval once again. Why could this be happening, and what could be the possible solution?

This is the c# code

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(listRetrieval));
    }

    public void frameChanger()
    {
        MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(PageReader));
    }

    private void tempButton_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(PageReader));
    }
}
```

And my XAML Code looks like this:

```
<Grid Background="#4a4a4a">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Name="tempButton" Content="Select a comic" Background="White" Height="50" Width="150" Click="tempButton_Click" />
        <Frame Name="MainFrame" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Wait, so you are trying to navigate to PageReader page when tempButton is clicked?

Comment: Possible solution, have you tried removing MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(listRetrieval)) from the MainPage constructor?

Comment: Please show the code you're using in the another class.

Comment: @devTimmy That was a function as well. I needed it to navigate it to the page PageReader everytime I invoke the function frameChanger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support... I guess I found the solution.
Don't call the frame by its name if you are in a different class. Rather just address it as 'Frame'

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(dispVolume));
```

This would access the current frame the user is working with and it would change the frame.